# "Son ustedes tan cerebrales."

Tags: verbos, orden-de-palabras

I saw the following sentence

> Son ustedes tan cerebrales.

translated as

> "you two are so irrational."

I think it would also be correct to say the following. Is that right?

> [Ustedes] son tan cerebrales.

Does the placement of "ustedes" after "son" serve to emphasize the "ustedes"? That is how I interpret the function of the word "two" in the English translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Son ustedes tan cerebrales.**

[Ustedes] son ​​tan cerebrales.

La respuesta corta es que es **correcto** decir "**son ​​tan cerebrales**". "Son (ustedes) tan cerebrales).

---

**Ampliando la cuestión**

> **Expanding the question**

Sin embargo, la cuestión es algo más complicada de lo que aparenta ya que va unida a la utilización del "tu" (tuteo) y el "usted" (ustedes / voseo).

> However, the issue is somewhat more complicated than it seems, since
> it is linked to the use of "tu" (tuteo) and "usted" (voseo).

Intentare explicarlo

> I will try to explain it

En América y en algunas partes del sur de España se utiliza el "usted" en lugar del "tu".

> In America and in some parts of southern Spain the "usted" is used
> instead of "tu".

Existe una regla poco conocida y así, si deseo ser formal utilizo la formula "**(Ustedes) son**". Si deseo ser coloquial o informal utilizo "**(Vosotros) sois**" .

> There is a little known rule and so, if I want to be formal I use the
> formula "**(Ustedes) son**". If I want to be colloquial or informal I
> use "**(Vosotros) sois**" .

Por ejemplo, la respuesta a una duda en la frase  "**Ana y tú son altas**" la RAE (La **R**eal **A**cademia **E**spañola), sobre la utilización de "**ustedes son** altas" o **"ustedes sois** altas" dice;

> For example, the response to a question in the phrase "**Ana y tú son
> altas**" ("Ana and you are tall") from the RAE (La **R**eal
> **A**cademia **E**spañola / The Royal Spanish Academy), on the use of "**ustedes son** altas" or **"ustedes sois ** altas" He says;

- Cuando se usa «**ustedes**» para el trato **formal** **o** para el **informal** (como en América, Canarias y parte de Andalucía), el verbo debe ir en **3.ª persona**: «**ustedes son altas**» (no se usa *ustedes sois).

> - When «**ustedes**» is used for the **formal** treatment **or** for the **informal** (as in America, the Canary Islands and part of
>   Andalusia), the verb must go in ** 3rd person**: “**ustedes **son
>   altas**” (*ustedes sois not used).

- Cuando se usa «**vosotros**», en **2.ª persona**: «vosotras **sois** altas».

> - When using «**vosotros**», in **2nd person**: «vosotras **sois** altas».

---

**Así es como interpreto la función de la palabra "two","dos" en la traducción al inglés.**

> **The function of the word "two" in the English translation.**

La colocación de "**ustedes**" después de "**son**" sirve efectivamente para enfatizar, por una parte a "ustedes", y también, para reconocer en la conversación que no existe "tuteo" (tu, hablar de tu, no hablar con formalismos).

> The placement of "**ustedes**" after "**son**" effectively serves to
> emphasize, on the one hand, "ustedes", and also, to recognize in the
> conversation that there is no "tuteo" (tu, hablar de tu, no hablar con
> formalismos), (you, not to speak with formalisms).

**Sois tan cerebrales**.

En español, si dices o escribes "**son ​​tan cerebrales**", y no conoces el contexto, puedes interpretarlo de forma errónea ya que puedes pensar que el sujeto son "Ellos", "**(Ellos) son tan cerebrales**" y no ustedes, es decir, "ellos son los otros, que no tienen nada que ver con ustedes", por tanto lleva a la confusión.

> In Spanish, if you say or write "**son ​​tan cerebrales**","**they are
> so cerebral**", and you don't know the context, you can interpret it
> wrongly since you may think that the subject is "Ellos", "They",
> "**(Ellos/They) are so cerebral **" and not you (ustedes), that is,
> "they are the others, who have nothing to do with you (ustedes o
> vosotros)", therefore it leads to confusion.

En inglés, no existen diferencias entre la 2ª persona del singular (tu/you) y la 2ª persona del plural (vosotros/ustedes/you), es por ello que en este caso se utiliza la palabra "dos", "**two**" tanto para referirse **a ti** (tu/vos) como **a los otros**, es decir, "**tu y los otros**".

> In English, there are no differences between the 2nd person singular
> (tu/you) and the 2nd person plural (vosotros/ustedes/you), which is
> why in this case the word "dos", "**two**" is used both to refer **to
> you** (you/you) as **to the others**, that is, "**you and the
> others**".

Así en la frase "**vosotros sois tan cerebrales**", estas refiriéndote a "vos" + "otros", a ti y a otros, es decir, "vosotros", "vos o tu" y los "otros", "Vosotros/Vos otros = Vos(tu) + Otros". "**Vos** y los **otros** sois tan cerebrales", son "dos", por eso se utiliza "dos", "two", y no confundirlo con "**ellos**".

Vos (tu) = 1

otros = 1

1 + 1 =  2 (Vosotros)

> Thus, in the phrase, "**vosotros sois tan cerebrales**", "**you are so
> cerebral**", you are referring to "a ti/you" + otros/"others", to you
> and to others, that is, "vosotros/you", "Vos or tu" and the otros,
> "others", " "Vosotros/Vos otros = Vos(tu) + Otros". "Vos,**You** and
> the Otros,**others** are so cerebral", are "dos", "two", that's why
> "dos", "two" is used, and not to be confused with "**them**".
>
> Vos (tu) = 1
>
> otros = 1
>
> 1 + 1 = 2 (Vosotros)

Comment: Al principio esta contestada, "correcta". Son ustedes tan cerebrales.

[Ustedes] son ​​tan cerebrales. Si se utiliza el "vosotros", más informal, se diría "Vosotros sois tan cerebrales". Aunque como explico una cosa es el contexto verbal y otra que lo encuentres escrito, en este sentido puedes confundirlo con ellos (Ellos) son tan cerebrales.

Comment: Thanks! Would one be more commonly used than the other? "Ustedes son tan cerebrales." "Son ustedes tan cerebrales."

Comment: En América se utiliza sobre todo "ustedes" (ustedes son) y en Europa "vosotros" (vosotros sois). Aunque siempre que se utilice "ustedes" se utiliza "ustedes son", como por ejemplo hablar con las personas mayores, cuando les hablas de usted. Aunque esto no ocurre en Argentina y otros lugares  donde es más usual utilizar el "ustedes sois".